# chi square on gender in two groups in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a chi square test on gender in two groups

```
#My data is: 
G1_F=10 #group 1, female
G1_M=14 #group2, male
G2_F=9
G2_M=15
```

I know the answer is a p-value on 0.77, but how do i get to this? 
If I make a matrix and calculate "chisq.test" (see below), I get the result: X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1

```
genderG = matrix( 
c(PDF, PDM, CF, CM), nrow=2, ncol=2) 
genderG

# Calculating p-sqaure and test statistics
chisq.test(genderG)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify option `correct = F`, in order to ignore the continuity correction that the command does by default.

```
G1_F=10 #group 1, female
G1_M=14 #group2, male
G2_F=9
G2_M=15

genderG = data.frame(G1 = c(G1_M, G1_F),
                     G2 = c(G2_M, G2_F))

chisq.test(genderG, correct = F)

# Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  genderG
# X-squared = 0.087114, df = 1, p-value = 0.7679
```

There's also another way to perform this test, using `prop.test`, but this time the inputs are observations in group 1 and total observations:

```
prop.test(genderG$G1, genderG$G1+genderG$G2, correct = F)

# 2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity
# correction
# 
# data:  genderG$G1 out of genderG$G1 + genderG$G2
# X-squared = 0.087114, df = 1, p-value = 0.7679
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   -0.3324899  0.2453756
# sample estimates:
#   prop 1    prop 2 
# 0.4827586 0.5263158
```